# How to copy text from a chrome extension using Async Clipboard API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I feel like I might be missing something simple.
I am trying to get a text from the clipboard using the [Async Clipboard Api](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi) but for the same strange reason, the operation is failing without any error messages.

I have a simple script that gets a text from the clipboard and then logs to console.

```
navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Text copied to clipboard', data);
    }).catch(err => {
    console.error("error copying text", err);
});
```

This fails with the message `error copying text undefined`.

In my manifest, I have requested the `clipboardRead` permission

```
  "permissions": [
    "clipboardRead"
  ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a bug, see https://crbug.com. You'll have to use the classic method via document.execCommand.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you have a specific link to the bug? Link above links to a list of unrelated bugs.

Comment: It's a link to the bug tracker for all the chromium bugs. The relevant one is probably https://crbug.com/874848

Comment: Thank you. If you wanna submit this as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this [Chromium bug](https://crbug.com/874848) where this issue is tracked. For a workaround that tried to use the new API and falls back to the legacy API, please see [this example](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/link-to-text-fragment/blob/master/background_script.js#L520-L537).